# No longer able to create modal on-the-fly with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm still trying to remove my jQuery training wheels.  I previously had a way to create a modal on-the-fly with jQuery.  It looked like this:

```
function showTheForm() {

    $rescheduleEmployeeModalHTML = $('<div>', {
        id: "rescheduleEmployeeModal",
        class: "modal",
        tabindex: "-1",
        role: "dialog",
        html: '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">' +
            '<div class="modal-content">' +
            '<div class="modal-header">' +
            '<h5 class="modal-title"></h5>' +
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">' +
            '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>' +
            '</button>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-footer">' +
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>' +
            '<button id="confirm_reschedule" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Reschedule</button>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>'
    }).on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        /**
         * directly manipulate the form when shown
         */
    }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        // self-cleanup
        $(this).remove();
    }).on('click', '#confirm_reschedule', function (e) {
        /**
         * explicit click listener
         */
    }).modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false,
        focus: true,
        show: true
    });

}

showTheForm();
```

In Bootstrap 5.1, I will need to use vanilla JavaScript, but I don't know how to "manifest" the modal into existence.

The html won't be in the DOM.  How do I create one on-the-fly and give it an `id` so that it could be referenced with `bootstrap.Modal.getInstance()` and the other Bootstrap methods?

I think I'm pretty close.  This is what I tried but it generates an error, shown below:

```
    let modal = document.createElement('div');
    modal.id = 'myModal';
    modal.className = 'modal';
    modal.setAttribute('tabindex', -1)
    modal.innerHTML = `<div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`;

    console.log(modal)

    var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(myModal, {
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true,
        focus: true,
        show: true
    })
```

Console error:

```
modal.js:313 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')
    at Hi._isAnimated (modal.js:313)
    at Hi._initializeBackDrop (modal.js:195)
    at new Hi (modal.js:83)
    at thisIsAFunction (main.js:34)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.js:55)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
```

Comment: var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(myModal, <---- look at the variable, you used the wrong one. You used the variable you are storing the reference, not the variable that has the DOM.

Comment: I had just caught that, thank you for looking!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, but please, if you can code this better, I would love to see how you do it.

Basically, I just had to pass in the actual JavaScript variable that contained the HTML structure:

```
    var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(modal, {
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true,
        focus: true,
    })

    myModal.show()
```

Notice the lowercase `modal` in `new bootstrap.Modal(modal, options)`